# Factorial inequality.

Tags: factorial

I have the following factorial function

$(m-k-1)!(k-1)!$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \geq 2$ and $k \in \{1,\cdots,m-1\}$.

I'm trying to find the value of $k$ for which the above expression attains minimum, or perhaps if there exists a function $f(m)$ such that

$f(m)! \leq (m-k-1)!(k-1)!$ for all $k \in \{1,\cdots,m-1\}$?

Plugging in certain values, it seems that the minimum is achieved for $k \approx m/2$, assuming $m$ is even. However, I have no idea about how to get the analytic expression.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try taking derivatives of the gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the lowest $k$ s.t. $(m-k-2)!k! \ge (m-k-1)!(k-1)!$

So we look for $k \ge m-k-1 \implies 2k \ge m-1$

Solving for the minimum $k_{min} =$ largest integer greater than or equal to $\dfrac{m-1}{2}$.

For odd $m$, this is $\dfrac{m-1}{2}$ and for even $m$, this is $\dfrac{m}{2}$

Comment: Hi Ross and Macavity, thanks both of you for your answers. Although they are correct, I'm afraid the proof might not be complete as all we have done is found a minimum. We'll have to additionally show that the function is convex so that any minimum is infact the global minimum. Have I got it correct?

Comment: @Amit factorial function is defined for natural numbers, so convexity is probably not the best way to go.  $\dfrac{m-1}{k}-1$ is the ratio of preceding term to succeeding one, which decreases steadily with $k$. At some point it crosses $1$, which is our minimum.

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks for this. I was trying to show convexity using the Gamma function as proposed by a previous post. Now everything is clear. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This method is not original by me.

Let
$f(k)
=(m-k-1)!(k-1)!
$.

Then
$r(k)
=\dfrac{f(k+1)}{f(k)}
=\dfrac{(m-(k+1)-1)!((k+1)-1)!}{(m-k-1)!(k-1)!}
=\dfrac{(m-k-2)!k!}{(m-k-1)!(k-1)!}
=\dfrac{k}{m-k-1}
$.

If $k < m-k-1$
(i.e., $k < \frac{m-1}{2}$),
$r(k) < 1$
so $f(k)$ is decreasing.

If $k > m-k-1$
(i.e., $k > \frac{m-1}{2}$),
$r(k) > 1$
so $f(k)$ is increasing.

If $m$ is odd,
then the minimum value
is at $k=\frac{m-1}{2}$.

If $m$ is even,
$r(\frac{m}{2})
=\frac{m/2}{m-m/2-1}
=\frac{m/2}{m/2-1}
>1
$
and
$r(\frac{m}{2}-1)
=\frac{m/2-1}{m-(m/2-1)-1}
=\frac{(m-2)/2}{(m-2)/2}
=1
$.

Therefore,
if $m$ is even,
the minimum value of $f(k)$
is at both
$k=\frac{m}{2}$
 and
$k=\frac{m}{2}-1$.